# Autoclosable, File resource in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to implement [AutoClosable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) InputStream in groovy but it is unable to recognize syntax for below snippet, which I took from my old project's Java class

```
try (InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(new File(relativePath))) {
    return IOUtils.toString(istream));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So instead I used `new File(relativePath).getText()` which works.

```
def static getTemplateAsString(def relativePath) {
    /*try (InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(new File(relativePath))) {
        return IOUtils.toString(istream));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    try {
        return new File(relativePath).getText()
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        fnfe.printStackTrace()
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace()
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

I have 2 questions

1. Does `new File(relativePath).getText()` auto release file resource similar to [AutoClosable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), where can I find it's doc?
2. Why isn't `try (InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(new File(relativePath)))` syntax working in groovy?

Groovy: 2.4.7,
JVM: 1.8.0_111

Comment: File.getText() groovy enhancement implements a try-finally and closes the stream. File.getText() calls [IOGroovyMethods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.html#getText(java.io.Reader)) which documents "the reader is closed before this method returns".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The try-with-resource syntax introduced in Java 7 is not directly supported in Groovy but the equivalent syntax uses *withCloseable* method (also with similar methods for streams and readers) and a closure block of code. Review [Groovy enhancements to File I/O](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) and the related [tutorial](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_working_with_io).

**Example:**

```
String text = null
new File(relativePath).withInputStream { istream ->
    text = IOUtils.toString(istream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return text
```

For the second part of the question, the File.getText() groovy enhancement implements a try-finally and closes the stream.

This does the same thing as the above code:

```
text = new File(relativePath).getText()
```

Comment: `toString(istream)` is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Groovy's try-with-resource idiom are the withXxx methods. In your case it's something like

```
new File(baseDir,'haiku.txt').withInputStream { stream ->
    // do something ...
}
```

See http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_working_with_io